# Get Authentication key, Mi band 5

Tags: java, authentication, xiaomi, mi

In the earlier versions of Mi Band such as Mi Band 3, pairing with third-party standalone was pretty easy. However, with the Mi Band 4, Xiaomi started hiding the Authentication key in the file system. This Authentication key is required to use the Mi Band without the Mi Fit app. Hence, I would just need to find out the Auth key.

This key seems to be generated by xiaomi online, but I think there is no api to use in 3rd party app.

Does anyone know how to generate this key? There are currently some solutions to find the **generated key by mi fit**, but this method **is not suitable** for a 3rd-party app.

Comment: Hi Alireza, did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: Hi Alireza, did you manage to get the data (heart rate, accelerometer and gyroscope) with mi band 4/5 (did you pursue this goal)? If so, could you please write how you did it? I followed the github code (https://github.com/satcar77/miband4), but I suspect that the data obtained is not correct, since the heart rate during visualization jumped when the hand moved and did not change if the hand was not moved

Comment: Dear Khava, ya, I read heart rate , but I develop an app with Java to read the data, also tested this linked project, this developed by phython, but I did not compare the results

Comment: @Alireza Could you write how you read the heart rate, what characteristics and what commands are sent to receive data?

Comment: BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic

  BluetoothGattService service = bluetoothGatt.getService("0000180D-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
  if (service == null) {
   return;
  }
  BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic("00002a39-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
  if (characteristic == null) {
   return;
  }


value = new byte[]{ 0x15, 0x02, 0x01 }
characteristic.setValue(value)
BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt
bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)

// write data to the characteristic and fetch receive data from callback @Khava